# nslayout constraint not making object appear

Tags: ios, swift4, nslayoutconstraint, subview

My code below is using code no storyboard to display a object. The project builds but I can not see the textfield I am trying to programmatically place. I dont know why the code is not appearing. I am trying to not use the storyboard.

```
 var enterWeight = UITextField()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(enterWeight)

    enterWeight.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue


    NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([

        enterWeight.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant : 20),
        enterWeight.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant : 20),
        enterWeight.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 20),
        enterWeight.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant : 20),


        enterWeight.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        enterWeight.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)

        ])

}
```

Comment: If you use Xcode's View Debugging feature, it can show you the view hierarchy of a running app's screen.  It can also tell you what constraints are in effect to make it look however it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting constraints and they will never work this way.

First, as mentioned by iFlames, you need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`:

```
enterWeight.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Then:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
        enterWeight.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant : 20),
        enterWeight.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 20),
        enterWeight.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant : 20),
        enterWeight.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
])
```

By giving the textField a leading and trailing you already gave it a width constraint implicitly, it's the width of `view` minus the constants (20 * 2), so you shouldn't give it a width constraint, it will cause a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`:

```
enterWeight.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: Its stating Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected element type 'NSLayoutConstraint.

Comment: Can you add that line before `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()` and not as a constraint in the array.